# Word for evaluating or understanding a system as a whole

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to rediscover a word I used to enjoy using but have forgotten. To mean something like: "Looking at something as a sum of its constituent interconnected parts". My dodgy brain keeps returning 'heuristic"...

"From a ____ point of view I would say...."

The opposite would be

"From a *granular* point of view I would say..."

Comment: I think maybe you are looking for aggregate or composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for *holistic*:

> 2 : relating to or concerned with wholes or with complete systems rather than with the analysis of, treatment of, or dissection into parts
>   // *holistic* medicine attempts to treat both the mind and the body
>   // *holistic* ecology views humans and the environment as a single system

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holistic))

Looking at individual letters, 'holistic' is not that much different from 'heuristic', so that would explain your recall of it. (Of course, it does mean something entirely different, but you know that already.)

Comment: Yes holistic! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

I think I'd go for *synoptic*. Literally, seeing [things] together. Sorry if this answer is too short.

Comment: Philip, a winning format for this sort of answer is to quote a dictionary definition, and provide the link.  Sometimes it's also good to include an example sentence.  Yes, this can be tedious, but it is best to follow this paradigm.